# Javascript doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a small problem with javascript on mobile. Website which I work on is [this](http://www.projects.carpatsoft.com/smart-cons.ro), and the problem is at the menu for mobiles. On desktop works like charm, but on mobile doesn't open the menu. I think the problem is JavaScript that doesn't work well. I don't get any warning in console.

```
document.getElementById("trigger-meniu-mobil").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("meniu-mobil").style.display="block";
};
document.getElementById("menu-close").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("meniu-mobil").style.display="none";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading a JavaScript file that does not exist on the server. Forget to upload maybe?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/attitude/library/js/meniu.js"></script>
```